# How to force K2 registration instead of joomla registration?

Tags: php, joomla, registration, joomla-k2

I have a site based on joomla & k2.
When user registred to the site with the standard joomla form, k2 does not assign the user to any group so the user can't submit items.
My question is: how can i force joomla to redirect users to the k2 registration form and disable the standard one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In the Joomla Backend, go to `Components >> K2` then click the **Parameters** buttons and go to the **Advanced** tab. In there you will find a parameter called **Enable K2 User Profile**, which you will need to make sure it set to "**yes**".

Once done, assuming you are using the standard Joomla registration component view, go to edit the menu item that is associated with the registration form, go to change the "**type**" and set it to the K2 registration form

Answer (score 0):

To enable the k2 one simply set the k2 login manager to all positions where the current login form is.

To disable the Joomla user names follow the Joomla documentation [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Disabling_user_registration).

Comment: thanks, I know the moduls you wrote about, but joomla redirects the user to the registration form when they try to send a new item etc. so i need to get them back to the k2 form.

Comment: Have you turned off the Joomla registration as per the second part of my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Create menu with k2 registration rather then using joomla default com_users.